# Using python-docx to batch print the name of the last user to modify

Tags: python, ms-office, batch-processing, python-docx

I'm trying to use Python to print the names of the last users to modify a bunch of documents (docx). In reality, this script should return a bunch of different names. I'm having to mix a bunch of different modules, but either I'm doing something wrong, or docx doesn't like the batch work. Has anybody got more experience with this that might be able to find the issue?

```
from docx import Document
import docx, glob, os

for filename in glob.glob('/Users/owner/Desktop/Rename/*.docx'):
fullfilename=os.path.abspath(filename)

document = Document('fullfilename')
core_properties = document.core_properties
print(core_properties.last_modified_by)
```

For reference, I've merged two scripts for this, and docx seemed to work well when it was one file at a time, is there something going wrong with my loop?:

```
from docx import Document
import docx

document = Document('mine.docx')
core_properties = document.core_properties
print(core_properties.last_modified_by)
```

I'm using Python 3.4 and docx 0.8.6

Comment: How is this linked to tag [tag:batch-file]??

Comment: Good call, clicked the wrong batch

Answer (score 0):

The main problem seems to be a lack of indenting. Python uses indentation (instead of curly braces) to determine what the block of your loop should be. So in this case it's only running through once. What you need is this:

```
import glob, os
from docx import Document

for filename in glob.glob('/Users/owner/Desktop/Rename/*.docx'):
    fullfilename = os.path.abspath(filename)
    document = Document('fullfilename')
    core_properties = document.core_properties
    print(core_properties.last_modified_by)
```

Note there is no need to import `docx`, since you don't use it (directly). In general, the `Document` object is all that needs importing in python-docx projects.

Comment: Thanks Scanny, I saw that you were pretty active with questions. I'm grateful you got back to me. :) I have actually indented my script, I must have overlooked it when I typed it in here. I've removed the second import docx, but I'm still getting issues. About 10 lines describing the path of each file a response ` Package not found at '%s % pkg_file ` rephrased in various ways.

Comment: @Josh: If you just print out the filename, do you get the filenames you're expecting? Also, I notice you put `fullfilename` in quotes, which of course would try to open the file named 'fullfilename'. Maybe you should do a little testing to try to narrow it down and then edit your question to make it more precise. In particular using the minimum exact code that's not working as well as stating exactly what the result is, along with any error messages. That will make it easier to be of help :) You can leave an @scanny comment to let us know to take another look.

Comment: Blummin heck @scanny that was quick! I tried to run it separately before I posted, but I'll have a closer look at the filename "portion" ASAP. Thanks mate :)